# Slack create new user

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-scim

I'm trying to create new users with Slack SCIM API. I've managed to create a new user without password but the invite email was newer sent. I've send following post to `https://api.slack.com/scim/v1/Users`

```
{
    "schemas": ["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0", 
     "urn:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:1.0"],
    "userName": "samplename",
    "nickName": "samplename",
    "name": {
        "familyName": "sample",
        "givenName": "name"
    },
    displayName": "sample name",
    "emails": [
        {
            "value": "sample.name@gmail.com",
            "type": "work",
            "primary": true
        }
    ],
    "userType": "sample",
    "title": "sample",
    "active":true
}
```

I can see the user created in the user list but never got the actual invite. (yes I checked spam). Is there even a way for this user to login?

Comment: have they even tried? have you tried looking in the admin tools and/or doing a password reset?

Comment: It seems that doing password reset works, the user got the invitation email. However that's a bit stupid for users to have to go trough password reset.